# Remove random N number of rows based on conditions on multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df

```
    Text column  Title     Numbers column
0          abc   rom-com               1
1          xyz    comedy               2
2           hi   rom-com               4
3          jkl    murder               5
4          abc  thriller               2
and so on................
```

**What I want:**

I want to **remove 5 random rows** where column Title has value **rom-com** and **remove random 6 rows** of column where title column has value **'murder'.**

**Code:**

```
df1 = df.drop(df[df['Title'].str.contains('rom-com')].sample(5).index & /
[df['Title'].str.contains('murder')].sample(6).index)
```

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sample'
```

Above code is working well for one title but not both together.

```
df1 = df.drop(df[df['Title'].str.contains('rom-com')].sample(5).index \
#this alone works for both murder and rom-com separately.
```

But both together I am not able to remove rows corresponding to values in multiple columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html):

```
df1 = df.drop(df[df['Title'].str.contains('rom-com')].sample(5).index.union(df[df['Title'].str.contains('murder')].sample(6).index))
```

Comment: what if there are multiple columns? Lets say I want to also remove 2 random instances where value of column is thriller. Will the same work even then?

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor - Yop, `df1 = df.drop(df[df['Title'].str.contains('rom-com')].sample(5).index.union(df[df['Title'].str.contains('murder')].sample(6).index).union(df[df['Title'].str.contains('thriller')].sample(2).index))`